# Should auto.register.schemas create a new version in schema-registry on modifying .avsc?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I've noticed a strange thing trying to follow a tutorial on Kafka schema-registry and a simple producer. It doesn't auto-generate new schema in schema-registry if I change the `.avsc` file. Steps I did:

1. Spin up a local schema-registry, Kafka and Zookeeper
2. Create `.avsc` file with 2 string fields
3. Create Java producer using `KafkaProducer` - I'm using avro-maven-plugin to generate a Java class out of the `.avsc` file.
4. Compile and run the producer - new Java class is generated and records are produced. Also, in the schema-registry a new entry appears.
5. Modify `.avsc` file - add a new field there
6. Compile - new Java class is generated with the new field. I add this field to the producer code.
7. **Run the producer** - no records are produced, no new version of the schema gets created in the schema registry but also I get no exception.

In the last step I expected the `auto.register.schemas` to create a new schema version, but it didn't. After I created it manually with curl in schema-registry, the records started to be produced correctly again.

I'm concerned that there was no Exception which made it hard to understand why the records are not produced.

Comment: Can you please share your producer code?

Answer (score 0):

If you only called send method with one (or few) message, then that's not going to be immediately sent to the broker, you'll need to flush the producer to do that. Ideally, by adding a shutdown hook to the JVM

Schemas only need to be registered when records get sent and serialized

Comment: I send 10 records and flush, it flushes successfully without an Exception yet records don't appear.

Comment: So, if you run a consumer from the beginning of the topic, you see nothing? Maybe there is no exception logged because you dont have SLF4J setup?